# I commit from my Microsoft Visual Studio, however, I am now seeing that i now have two versions of two files

Tags: c#, git, github, visual-studio-2010, github-for-windows

[image: Error Image]

I have issues with my commit, two files in my repo are being duplicated. My Logics.cs and Constants.cs were duplicated. I really do not know why that happened, I made the commit from my Microsoft Visual studio.

I do not want to delete manual, to not affect any of the files. Please assist.

Comment: Did you rename the files? They seem to have different case in the filenames of the duplicates.

Comment: I did not rename them. They happened automatically. I could not phantom why.

Comment: You can look at the history of an individual file by running `git log --since=2024-01-01 -- Constants.cs` for instance. That should give you an idea of when those duplicates we introduced. And I highly recommend using `gitk --all` to inspect the version history, it will show you everything that has been made of commits.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is seams like you  added the same files with different names or paths

you need to revert the commit in witch you added the duplicate

> git revert "SHA hash of the commit"

then resolve the conflicts

finally commit again and push to your branch (please dont name another branch name )